# Poltergeist-phantomjs - switching to the new popped up window

Tags: ui-automation, poltergeist, headless-browser

Test env: Capybara,poltergeist, phantomjs.

A new window opens up when I click a link in my test case. I was able to switch to the new window and verify text using selenium driver. However, I am unable to switch to the new window with poltergeist. I tried the following method to switch to the new window and none of them worked.
I  wanted to see if a new browser is getting open at all and looks like it is.

```
main = page.driver.browser.window_handles.first
        puts main (gives 0)
        popup = page.driver.browser.window_handles.last
        puts popup (gives 1) 

   1.  within_window(->{ page.title == '2015-11-5.pdf' }) { assert_text(facility_name) }
   2.  page.switch_to_window(window=popup)
   3.  page.switch_to_window(page.driver.browser.window_handles.last)
   4.  page.driver.browser.switch_to().window(page.driver.browser.window_handles.last)
```

Could someone provide any inputs here? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I used the following and the popup is getting generated and the control switches to it.

```
page.switch_to_window(page.window_opened_by{click_link('Generate Report')})
```

The new window has a pdf embedded in it.I was able to read and verify the contents of the document when I use selenium driver. With poltergeist, I am unable to read the pdf. Could you give me some pointers on how to proceed?

Comment: This implementation is just what I wanted. Only I used this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555502/poltergeist-phantomjs-switching-to-the-new-popped-up-window#answer-33557805) to become more organized my code

Answer (score 2):

Capybara has a number of cross driver methods for dealing with this without having to go to driver specific methods.

```
popup = page.window_opened_by {
  click_link('whatever link opens the new window')
}
within_window(popup) do
 # perform actions in the new window
end
```

Comment: really enjoyed, to be a very elegant implementation